# dask visualize() KeyError

Tags: graphviz, jupyter-notebook, dot, dask

I have been successfully visualizing `dask` objects for a few days now, but I just restarted my Jupyter notebook kernel and am running into a `KeyError` that I can't seem to debug.

Before I restarted the kernel, the following code worked fine:

```
def sigmoid(x):
    '''Sigmoid function of x.'''
    return 1/(1+da.exp(-x))

X = da.from_array(np.random.random((4,2)), chunks=2)
beta = np.ones((2,1))

## 
p = (X.dot(beta)).map_blocks(sigmoid)
W = da.diag((p*(1-p))[:,0])
hessian = da.dot(X.T.dot(W),X)
hessian.visualize()
```

But now when I run, I get the following traceback:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-660a47cb4654> in <module>()
      7 W = da.diag((p*(1-p))[:,0])
      8 hessian = dot(X.T.dot(W),X)
----> 9 hessian.visualize()

.../anaconda3/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/base.py in visualize(self, filename, format, optimize_graph, **kwargs)
     59         """
     60         return visualize(self, filename=filename, format=format,
---> 61                          optimize_graph=optimize_graph, **kwargs)
     62 
     63     def compute(self, **kwargs):

.../anaconda3/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/base.py in visualize(*args, **kwargs)
    234     dsk = merge(dsks)
    235 
--> 236     return dot_graph(dsk, filename=filename, **kwargs)
    237 
    238 

.../anaconda3/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dot.py in dot_graph(dsk, filename, format, **kwargs)
    217     dask.dot.to_graphviz
    218     """
--> 219     g = to_graphviz(dsk, **kwargs)
    220 
    221     fmts = ['.png', '.pdf', '.dot', '.svg', '.jpeg', '.jpg']

.../anaconda3/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dot.py in to_graphviz(dsk, data_attributes, function_attributes, rankdir, graph_attr, node_attr, edge_attr, **kwargs)
    130             if func_name not in seen:
    131                 seen.add(func_name)
--> 132                 g.node(func_name, label=task_label(v), shape='circle',
    133                        **function_attributes.get(k, {}))
    134             g.edge(func_name, k_name)

.../anaconda3/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dot.py in task_label(task)
     29     if hasattr(func, 'funcs'):
     30         if len(func.funcs) > 1:
---> 31             return '{0}(...)'.format(funcname(func.funcs[0]))
     32         else:
     33             head = funcname(func.funcs[0])

KeyError: 0
```

It appears there is some label missing for one of the tasks or something like that?

**EDIT:** Actually, to reproduce the error you need to modify the sigmoid function as follows:

```
from multipledispatch import dispatch

@dispatch(da.Array)
def sigmoid(x):
    '''Sigmoid function of x.'''
    return 1/(1+da.exp(-x))

@dispatch(np.ndarray)
def sigmoid(x):
    '''Sigmoid function of x.'''
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reproducible example.

Unfortunately, this runs fine for me:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import dask.array as da

In [3]: from multipledispatch import dispatch
   ...: 
   ...: @dispatch(da.Array)
   ...: def sigmoid(x):
   ...:     '''Sigmoid function of x.'''
   ...:     return 1/(1+da.exp(-x))
   ...: 
   ...: @dispatch(np.ndarray)
   ...: def sigmoid(x):
   ...:     '''Sigmoid function of x.'''
   ...:     return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
   ...: 

In [4]: pdb
Automatic pdb calling has been turned ON

In [5]: def sigmoid(x):
   ...:     '''Sigmoid function of x.'''
   ...:     return 1/(1+da.exp(-x))
   ...: 
   ...: X = da.from_array(np.random.random((4,2)), chunks=2)
   ...: beta = np.ones((2,1))
   ...: 
   ...: ## 
   ...: p = (X.dot(beta)).map_blocks(sigmoid)
   ...: W = da.diag((p*(1-p))[:,0])
   ...: hessian = da.dot(X.T.dot(W),X)
   ...: hessian.visualize()
   ...: 
Out[5]: <IPython.core.display.Image object>
```

The fact that it worked until you restarted something is a bit odd.  Perhaps something is up with your environment?

Comment: Hmm your comment on reproducibility got me thinking -- the code I pasted actually *does* run for me as well!  I edited the post to fully reproduce the code I'm working with, and now I suspect you'll have a `KeyError`.

Comment: Looks like you overrode the dispatch sigmoid with a new dask-only sigmoid function in cell block [5].

Comment: Ah, indeed. Reproduced.